# "Row Not Found or Unchanged" Error on SubmitChanges Call

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I am getting the following error: "row not found or unchanged" on calling submitchanges() method.

Here is my code.

```
datacontex1 data = new datacontex1() ;

var query = from p in data.projects
            where p.id == myid
            select p;

foreach(project p in query)
{
    p.status="completed"
}

data.submitchanges();
```

Comment: Try after updating query filtering out 'completed' status projects. e.g. from p in data.projects where p.status != "completed" and p.id == myid select p;

Comment: Well, that's not your real code, because `submitchanges` should be `SubmitChanges`. Please post *actual* code which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What kind of LINQ? LINQ to SharePoint?

Comment: @John Linq to sql,@jon the logic is same,@softwaredeveloper in my database there is no row exist which has "completed" status so i think is no problem in that part

Comment: @jon nice observation :)

Comment: Do you have any database constraints on the table? Also check if you have a primary key set up correctly.

Comment: In that case your query is meant to select just one item? That's confusing - why are you setting the status in a loop then?

Comment: @saurabh did you find out an answer to your question?

Comment: Nopes.instead of writing the LINQ query now i'm using sqldatasource  control and there i have added the update parameter to it . and it is working fine.

Comment: if you need any help i can post you the code .tomorrow. i don't have it now

Answer (score -1):

you should use a normal For statement, the foreach statement is readonly!

instead of:

```
foreach(project p in query)
{
    p.status="completed"
}
```

you should do something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < query.items.count; i++)
{     
     query.items[i].status = "completed"
}
```